# Why i cant acces my web service on port 80

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver, iis

I have a static public ip, and a ISS service with application  with this bindings (ip :* ports:80, 7153):
[image: iis web site bindings]

I added rules to my firewall to allow any connection on this ports.
Also I've configured port forwarding like that (192.168.1.4 is address of iis pool server) :
[image: router port forwarding configuration]

But for some reason I can reach site by public_ip:7153, but can't reach website on generic http port (80), and because of this I can't properly apply my domain name to my website.

Comment: Could your ISP be blocking ports ? Ive known some ISPs block ports below 1024 for non-commercial users for example.

Comment: ISPs blocks port 80? this is would be very weird, 80 and 443 is default ports for Web Browsers.

Comment: I stated 'for non commercial users'. Its a way to force customers to upgrade to business plans. I can only see it being that or a firewall misconfiguration.

Comment: But if provider will block port 80 even for non commercial user they wouldnt manage to use  web browser, port 80 and 443 is default port for web browsers? Right?

Comment: For incoming traffic, yes. Since it works for you on port 7153 but no on 80, i thought i'd mention it as a possibility. I'm currently using a provider that blocks incoming traffic to ports under 1024 for non-commercial users.

Comment: Additional Info, I can use Public Ip with port 80 in local host to get resource, I will get response. But when I'm trying to use same address outside local host I get "This site can’t be reached", also I've got response from my ISP, they told me that they do not block any ports.